# Caret NNest: Groups of categorical variable are empty?

Tags: r, caret, nnet

I want to train a `NNet` with `Caret` in R. For that, I created a response variable of my data like this:

```
                  Class
2165                  0
4146                  0
18212                 1
9439                  0
12589                 1
18756                 1
```

Because I want to use `ROC` as  a metric, I changed the levels to valid names, i.e.

```
levels(data$y_train$Class) <- c("no", "yes")
                  Class
2165                 no
4146                 no
18212               yes
9439                 no
12589               yes
18756               yes
```

With this data I can successfully train `glm, rpart, rf`....However, when using `NNet` like this

```
control <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=1, repeats = 1, search = "random", classProbs = TRUE,
                        summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)
nnet_model <- train(x = data$x_train, y = data$y_train$Class, method="nnet",  tuneLength = 1, 
                    trControl = control, metric = "ROC")
```

I always get the warning:

```
Warning in nnet.formula(.outcome ~ ., data = dat, size = param$size, decay = param$decay,  :
  Groups ‘no’ ‘yes’ are empty
```

and the model does not learn anything, i.e. `ROC` at 0.5

What's the problem here?

EDIT:
concrete dummy example that yields the same issue:

```
data_example <- tibble(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 2), class = c(0,0, 1, 1))
data_example$class <- as.factor(data_example$class)
levels(data_example$class) <- c("no", "yes")

control <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=1, repeats = 1, search = "random", classProbs = TRUE,
                        summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)
nnet_model <- train(x = data_example %>% select(-class), y = data_example$class, method="nnet",  tuneLength = 1, 
                    trControl = control, metric = "ROC")
```

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72375395/edit) with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is a placeholder for the name of your data set.)

Comment: I did add a conrete example

Comment: See what you have in `data_example$class` after setting the levels to values other than 0 and 1. The right way is to assign the *labels* attribute to no, yes: `data_example$class <- factor(data_example$class, labels = c("no", "yes"))`.